# Trouble adding comment relation to User table in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

so I just got done following python YouTuber Corey Schafers tutorial on flask-sqlalchemy. I'm having problems modifying the DB we created. I'm trying to make a relation to my Comment table and User table. When a user posts a comment I want to store the user's name. So far I can't seem to link a user's comment on a post to the name of the author of the comment. This is the code that's relevant.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from smushd_site import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask import current_app



@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    #comments_name = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author_comment', lazy=True)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)



    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"



class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False,default="stalin")
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    #poster_id = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('poster.id'), nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)
    #comment_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    #username = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    #comment_name = db.relationship('User', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Comment('{self.body}', '{self.timestamp}')"
```

These are the link to the repo with the code and youtube series:
https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/Flask_Blog/12-Error-Pages/flaskblog/models.py
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYWiDiIUxQc&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=4

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wrote; it might help you. `Feedback` is just an example - you can do the same thing with `Comment`.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __bind_key__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    username = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False) 
    email = db.Column(db.String(125), unique=True, nullable=False) 
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg') 
    password = db.Column(db.String(65), nullable=False) 
    about = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False) 
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True) 
    feedbacks = db.relationship('Feedback', backref='author', lazy=True) 
    create_account = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
    badges = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)

class Feedback(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'feedback'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False) 
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```